# accessing attribute from a list

Tags: angularjs

i want to access period in items as options in select tag.

angular js module and list

```
     var dynamicApp = angular.module('dynamicApp', []);  
       dynamicApp.controller('maincontroller', function($scope) {
    $scope.invoice = {
    items: [{
         loyality: [{name:'points'},{name:'credits'}],
         value:1,
    period: [{name:'activity1'},{name:'activity2'}]
        }]
  };
      $scope.removeItem = function(index) {
    $scope.list.splice(index, 1);
   }    

    });
```

html code for  select tag

```
 <td><select ng-model=" pts"  ng-options="lists.items.period for lists in   invoice.items  " ></select></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the HTML code:

```
<select ng-model="pts" ng-options="item as item.name for item in invoice.items[0].period track by $index" ></select>
```

and also a working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/OZxcsMIVDs78Jbama174?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
<select ng-model=" pts"  ng-options="lists for lists in invoice.items.period  " ></select>
</td>
```